# Oracle apex 19.1 (user Authentication and Authorisation)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm creating an app (app x) which will require certain parts of the app to be protected. I essentially need an authorization prompt to reject/accept access selectively. Quick example of the desired result:

- Within app x there is a diary application regarding tax returns
- John selects the diary icon, he then enters his username, and password.
- John is now given access.
- Lisa attempts to access the diary however her login credentials are rejected.*

As you can see in this example John is an Authorized user, Lisa is not.

**How do i implement this on apex?**

A step by step guide would me much appreciated. I am also slightly confused with the difference between Authentication, and Authorization.

Comment: Hi yaya30001996, did you still need help with this? Was Littlefoot's answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Create table which holds info about privileges, for example

```
create table priv
  (app_user varchar2(30),
   priv     varchar2(20) 
  );

insert into priv (app_user, priv) 
  select 'JOHN', 'admin' from dual union all
  select 'LISA', 'oper'  from dual;
```

Now create set of functions (preferably contained in a package) which will - for every user - return whether they are (or are not) granted certain privileges. You can choose to return Boolean, but - then you can't use it in pure SQL.

```
create or replace function f_priv_admin_01 (par_app_user in varchar2)
  return number
is
  -- return 1 if PAR_APP_USER is admin; return 0 otherwise
  retval number := 0;
begin
  select 1
  into retval
  from priv
  where app_user = par_app_user
    and priv = 'admin';

  return retval;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return retval;
end;
```

In your Apex application, using "Server side condition", use "Function that returns Boolean", e.g.

```
return f_priv_admin_01 (:APP_USER) = 1;
```

which says: if user currently logged in is 'admin', display that page/region/diary whatever. Otherwise, don't.